# httaccess, all rewrite is redirecting to index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Hi i have a some problem with .htaccess, I need make url structure like this: https://example.com/folder/name1

folder - is directory with all files, .htaccess, indexes etc..

name1 - is parameter for backend, mysql etc...

In my .htaccess, I have this code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/shop shop.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)/voucher/ voucher.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/voucher voucher.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)/rules/ rules.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/rules rules.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)/item/(.*)/ item.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/item/(.*) item.php?id=$2

RewriteRule ^(.*)/item/ item.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/item item.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)/ index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

And problem is with two last lines, because when I go to https://example.com/folder/name1 is working, I seed index.php file, but when I go https://example.com/folder/name1/shop I still see index.php. Where is problem?

Answer (score 0):

All of your rewrite rules should have the "last" flag on them (`[L]`) which tells mod_rewrite not to process other rules after.  What is happening is this your last rule matches all requests, even ones that have been previously rewritten.

```sh
RewriteRule ^(.*)/shop shop.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/voucher/ voucher.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/voucher voucher.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/rules/ rules.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/rules rules.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/item/(.*)/ item.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/item/(.*) item.php?id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/item/ item.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/item item.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
```

Comment: No working, further redirects to index.php when i go to https://example.com/folder/name1/shop

Comment: I used flag [B] on RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php and its working :D
Thanks for your time!